# CCParticle define a region?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to define a region to my snow, when its now in the rect of the screen, but my game using twice the height of he screen and so, i want it to start from 2*screenHeigh.

How to change that property ?

```
   CCTexture2D *tex=[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"snow.png"];
    CCParticleSnow *emitter =  [CCParticleSnow node];

    [emitter setTexture:tex ];
    emitter.scale=0.7;
    emitter.speed = 120 + arc4random() %20;




[self addChild: emitter z:-1];
```

Comment: set the emitter's position, tried that?

Comment: Yes, its only a position , the size still in the screen size .